# How to know which application is reading or writing file

Tags: android, linux, file, android-ndk, linux-kernel

Is there any way in way in Android or in Android NDK to know which application is reading or writing data on disk or device memory?

Comment: I've re-read your question. At first I thought you wanted to do this by code... now I see that you just need a memory-resident debugger like softICE or something that can breakpoint on memory access.

Comment: @Shark I want to do this by code itself

Comment: Then I guess you would need to figure out how to give your APK root permissions; I don't want to sound offending or anything but it looks like you're making a sniffer of some sort - so figuring out how to elevate your app would be the first major problem imo.

Comment: @Shark just look at this http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/   this is the code in python,can u convert the following code to C code through http://sourceforge.net/projects/py2cmod/files/latest/download ,as i don't know python at all

Comment: Looks feasible, give it a shot :)

Comment: @Shark I don't know python even a bit.....

Comment: @Shark can u explain the output of ls -l /proc/*/fd/ and ls -l /data/data please

Comment: I extracted them both, ran "python py2cmod.py iotop/__init__.py and got an __init__.c file ... so try it. However, that doesn't really seem to be it, I don't think the C file will compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there is a SDK way of doing it but Linux will allow you to list processes/open files/sockets and you can try grabbing things from there.

First use ps command to get PID of process, enter:

```
$ ps -aef | grep {process-name}
$ ps -aef | grep httpd
```

Next pass this PID to pfiles command,

```
$ pfiles {PID}
$ pfile 3533
```

This is how you'd list all open files used by firefox...

```
lsof -p `ps -C firefox -o pid=`
```

You can use System.exec() to execute these, but you also need to have root access. Which is something you had to have to view that kind of information anyway I suppose...

EDIT:

this is what i got from Py2Cmod

init.c

```
/* Generated by py2cmod
*
* py2cmod (c) 2001 Mark Rowe
*/

#include "Python.h"

static PyObject *ErrorObject;

/* ----------------------------------------------------- */

/* List of methods defined in the module */

static struct PyMethodDef iotop/__init___methods[] = {

{NULL,   (PyCFunction)NULL, 0, NULL}        /* sentinel */
};


/* Initialization function for the module (*must* be called initiotop/__init__) */

static char iotop/__init___module_documentation[] =  "";

void initiotop/__init__()
{
PyObject *m, *d;

/* Create the module and add the functions */
m = Py_InitModule4("iotop/__init__", iotop/__init___methods,
    iotop/__init___module_documentation,
    (PyObject*)NULL,PYTHON_API_VERSION);

/* Add some symbolic constants to the module */
d = PyModule_GetDict(m);
ErrorObject = PyString_FromString("iotop/__init__.error");
PyDict_SetItemString(d, "error", ErrorObject);

/* XXXX Add constants here */
PyDict_SetItemString(d, "__file__", PyString_FromString("iotop/__init__.py"));
PyDict_SetItemString(d, "__name__", PyString_FromString("iotop/__init__"));


/* Check for errors */
if (PyErr_Occurred())
    Py_FatalError("can't initialize module iotop/__init__");
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but i don't have the root permission and sir i want the pid or process name of the processes that are writing or reading from disk

Comment: How do you imagine going about other processes's data or snooping around for what's writing where if you have basic APK privileges? Even on linux you cannot do that without sudo.

Comment: i don't want to know that "what's writing where" i only want to know something is being written or being read from memory and specially the application name or pid that is writing or reading

Comment: I guess you're making a "notify-on-memory-access" service then... I would really suggest developing this first for Linux and then porting it over to Android since I guess these will share alot of lowlevel unix code. But <b>PERMISSIONS</b> will be your big ache. I really don't think you can do this without sudo (or better said with APK permissions)...

Comment: moreover, AndroidManifest.xml must have a permission to let your app scour through the user's phone memory which might turn some people off your app.

Answer (score 1):

You may look for your file in the output of

> ls -l /proc/*/fd/

You do not need no special tool or root for this.

**Explanation**:

Every running process gets an entry in `/proc/` named after it's pid. For every pid the is a directory `fd` with symlinks with the name of the filehandle pointing to the filename.

One entry for instance may ...

> lr-x------ app_25   app_25            2012-09-06 12:16 20 ->
>   /system/etc/fallback_fonts.xml

Unfortunatly we do not see the PID, but we can see the process owner `app_25`.

Therefore we can look into `/data/data/` (with `ls -l /data/data`)

```
...
drwxr-x--x app_9    app_9             2012-02-23 08:31 com.android.launcher 
drwxr-x--x app_25   app_25            2012-02-23 08:30 com.android.mms 
drwxr-x--x app_5    app_5             2012-02-23 08:29 com.android.music
...
```

So it is application `com.android.mms`

Comment: @user707424 sir thanks for the reply,i think u didn't get me,i want to know which application is reading or writing file in memory,it can be any file(can be mine file or not)

Comment: (I renamed myself user707424 to 0x01af) Ok. Thats a little bit complicated, since ls is very basic in android: The PID of the process is the * part of the file name. unfortunatly it is not displayed. But if you are looking for user supplied apps, you may have a look to the owner and compare with the installation base of the app.

Comment: I have added an explanation to my answer

Comment: @sixeightzero sir i wrote the output of my ls -l command can u tell what should i do now?

Comment: sir according to "sixeightzero" comment, i pasted my ls -l result, what should i do now?

Comment: i did that said that is "ls -l /proc/*/fd/" and got many enteries now can u tell what to do?

Comment: why did u take the entry that have "lr-x" in starting what does "lr-x" stand for? and what is the output of "ls -l /proc/*/fd/" tell us?

Comment: @sixeightzero why did u take the entry that have "lr-x" in starting what does "lr-x" stand for? and what is the output of "ls -l /proc/*/fd/" tell us?

Comment: i want to know the exact location of file,from pid i can the app name

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you mean by "reading or writing data on disk or device memory", but I hope the [dumpsys](http://wrightrocket.blogspot.co.il/2010/12/useful-commands-in-adb-shell.html) tool can help.

Comment: by "reading or writing data on disk or device memory" i mean that i want to know which application is reading or writing a file in our device memory or on sd card and dumpsys doesn't work on Android 2.3

Comment: dumpsys works for me on all 2.2 and 2.3 devices I tested. The format of its output may be slightly different.

Comment: in 2.3 when i run dumpsys programmatic-ally for some services it says "Permission Denial: can't dump MediaPlayerService from pid=356, uid=10035" and how can it solve my problem,please tell i will be very helpfull tou you