# Is there any way in Android to know which application is reading or writing data on disk or device memory programmatically

Tags: android, file-io, filesystems

I'm trying to exercise what is been suggested by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12300003/829571) as I found it quite suiting answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299772/how-to-know-which-application-is-reading-or-writing-file-in-android).

Accordingly I've executed `ls -l /proc/` in my java app using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec`.

I got to see running processes details as those got entry into this folder, but for PID.

For getting application details of the process owner (eg. app_25), 
I've looked into /data/data/ (with `ls -l /data/data`). I expected to have contents from this folder in following fashion.

```
drwxr-x--x app_25   app_25            2012-02-23 08:30 com.android.mms
```

Unfortunately, I do not get to see any results. I intended to map process owner from previous result set of `ls -l /proc/` to process owner of current result set `ls -l /data/data`. Am I going wrong in anyway?